# Angular "on" event not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

And weirdly it seems to be highlighted strangely in my ide, see below nothing else is this colour, using angular.js 1.218

[image]

Do I have to include something to get this functionality ?

(coffeescript btw)

Comment: I noticed that you spelled "location" wrong in your alert.  Did you do the same in your target?

Comment: @RobertHarvey target ? the event is locationChangeStart. Although i tried others.

Comment: The event appears to only occur [on the root scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location). Is the `$scope` in the snippet that or [a descendant of it](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-hierarchies)? You could try referencing [`$rootScope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24rootScope) instead.